# Dual of completion and weak$^*$-topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, weak-convergence, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a dense subspace of a Banach space $Y$. The restriction map
$$r: Y^* \to X^*:\omega \mapsto  \omega \vert_X$$
is then an isometric isomorphism that is weak$^*$-continuous.

I am wondering if it is true if the map $r$ is a weak $^*$-homeomorphism? My intuition tells me that this is not true.

Of course, on norm-bounded subsets, the inverse map is weak$^*$-continuous, so the problem (if any) exists because of the unbounded nature of things.

Any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theorem 3.10 in Rudin Functional Analysis "Suppose $X$ is a vector space and $X'$ is a separating vector space of linear functionals on $X$.  Then the $X'$-topology $\tau'$ makes $X$ into a locally convex space **whose dual space** is $X'$."

Now consider the situation you're talking about.  $X$ is a dense subspace of $Y$.  If $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\in Y^*$ and $\alpha_1\rvert_X=\alpha_2\rvert_X$ then $\alpha_1=\alpha_2$ because $X$ is dense.  This means that $X$ separates points on $Y^*$.  Of course, $Y$ also separates points on $Y^*$.  You're considering two topologies on $Y^*$.  $\tau_X$ is the topology from $X$ as linear functionals on $Y^*$.  $\tau_Y$ is the topology from $Y$ as linear functionals on $Y^*$.  By the theorem quoted above, the dual of $(Y^*,\tau_X)$ is $X$ and the dual of $(Y^*,\tau_Y)$ is $Y$, so the topologies $\tau_X,\tau_Y$ cannot be identical except when $X=Y$.

Here is something more explicit: Assume $X\subsetneq Y$ and let $y\in Y\setminus X$.  Then $y\ne 0$.  The linear functional $p:Y^*\to\Bbb{C}$ defined by $p(\alpha)=\alpha(y)$ is weak-$Y^*$ continuous on $Y^*$.  Assume $r^{-1}$ is continuous from the weak-$X^*$ topology to the weak-$Y^*$ topology.  Let $q:X^*\to\Bbb{C}$ be the linear functional $q(\beta)=p(r^{-1}(\beta))$.  Since $q$ is a composition of continuous maps, it is continuous in the weak-$X^*$ topology on $X^*$.

Since $q$ is weak-$X^*$ continuous, there exist $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in X$ and $C>0$ such that
$$|q(\beta)|\le C\sum_{i=1}^n|\beta(x_i)|\tag{1}$$
for all $\beta\in X^*$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165965)).

Since $\operatorname{span}\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}\subseteq X$ and $y\not\in X$, there is an $\alpha_0\in Y^*$ such that $\alpha_0(x_i)=0$ for all $i, 1\le i\le n$ and $\alpha_0(y)=\|y\|\ne 0$ (this is by Hahn-Banach.)  Now let $\beta_0=r(\alpha_0)=\alpha_0\rvert_X$.  Then $\beta_0(x_i)=(r(\alpha_0))(x_i)=\alpha_0\rvert_X(x_i)=\alpha_0(x_i)=0$ for all $i,1\le i\le n$.  And $q(\beta_0)=p(r^{-1}(\beta_0))=p(\alpha_0)=\alpha_0(y)\ne 0$.  This contradicts $(1)$ (taking $\beta=\beta_0$).  Therefore $r^{-1}$ cannot have the continuity presumed.

Comment: Excellent answer! Thanks!